# How do you get to convert an excel file into a MySQL file?

Tags: mysql, excel

I have a 6,5 MB XLSX file and I want to get a MySQL file from it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just basic data save it as a CSV.

Import with

```
 Load data infile
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html